# New vs Renewal membership issues

Tags: civimember

Edit Jan 5, 2022: It's a new year and membership renewals are coming in. The admins are asking me to show renewals as status "Current" (not "New") in the membership dashboard. I still don't know how to do this. Is Civicrm even capable of this (if the user is not logged into Wordpress when using the form)?

We are on Wordpress 5.8 and Civicrm 5.34.0.
We do not allow Wordpress user accounts/signups, except for our admins. So from what I can tell from the books, the public membership form will always be in the new member mode. I have titled the form to indicate that it will work for renewals as well as new.

The problem is that the automatic deduping seems to fail. All the renewals are coming in as new memberships with incorrect 'Member Since' dates. I'd like renewals to appear with status = Current ("Renewal" would be nice but appears that is not one of the allowed values) in the membership dashboard. I don't work with Civicrm very much and need guidance, if you can think of something to help.

Dedup Rules:

There are a lot of rules, so let's just look at our 5 individual rules first. There are the 3 reserved rules, marked as 'General' usage.

```
Email (reserved)    General

First, Last and Email (reserved) General

Name and Address (reserved) General
```

Then there are 2 more individual rules that match on email only. I put these in a while ago I think, and I'm not sure about the weight/threshold settings.

```
Email Only 3    Supervised  (Email weight = 1, Length not set, threshold = 1)

Email Only 2    Unsupervised  (Email weight = 1, Length not set, threshold = 1)
```

None of these rules are finding any dups at the moment.

Comment: pls explain what your matching rules are

Comment: See edits to question.

Comment: you saw my comments below about using checksums and reminders?

Comment: The admins are not up to speed on getting email to work at all. I had a lot of trouble with testing emails myself a couple of years ago. I think I had to set up cron jobs etc. But this would be good partial solution to the renewal problem. Mostly folks just go directly to the site to renew. I will revisit getting the emails to work.

Comment: "(how) to show renewals as status "Current" (not "New")" - if civi was working as intended then someone who renews 'extends' the End Date of their existing membership, and hence they would show as Current, not New (unless you have modified the Membership Status settings - in which case I suggest you compare with a demo site eg http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/

Answer (score 4):

It won't be in the 'new member' mode if you send out renewal reminders from civicrm using an email template that uses a checksum - that way the system knows who is filling in the form, it prefills most info, and hence it would know they had an existing membership to renew.

Comment: We don't use email reminders from Civicrm. It's been too hard to set up and get working.

Comment: That's a shame, as it makes everything else join together more easily.